# How to locate a div with specific text and test id with Playwright?

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, playwright, angularjs-e2e, e2e

I have a HTML like this:

```html
<div>
  <div>Internal Description</div>
  <app-rich-text-editor>
    <div data-testid="rich-text-editor">
    </div>
  </app-rich-text-editor>
</div>

<div>
  <div>External Description</div>
  <app-rich-text-editor>
    <div data-testid="rich-text-editor">
    </div>
  </app-rich-text-editor>
</div>
```

If I locate the div with
`await page.getByTestId('rich-text-editor')`
I get both divs. The difference between them are the text 'Internal Description' and 'External Description'. How to locate the first div with `data-testid="rich-text-editor"` and parent-parallel `<div>Internal Description</div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work top-down:

1. Select the `<div>` by text
2. Use the `+` CSS selector to grab the next `<app-rich-text-editor>` sibling
3. Use the `getByTestId` function to select by `[data-testid="rich-text-editor"]`.

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0


const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<div>
  <div>Internal Description</div>
  <app-rich-text-editor>
    <div data-testid="rich-text-editor"></div>
  </app-rich-text-editor>
</div>
<div>
  <div>External Description</div>
  <app-rich-text-editor>
    <div data-testid="rich-text-editor"></div>
  </app-rich-text-editor>
</div>
</body></html>`;

test("'Internal Description' div with rich-text-editor is visible", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  const loc = page.getByText("Internal Description")
    .locator("+ app-rich-text-editor")
    .getByTestId("rich-text-editor");
  await expect(loc).toBeVisible();
});
```

It's also possible to use the attribute child selector since you're in CSS selector context anyway:

```js
const loc = page.getByText("Internal Description")
  .locator('+ app-rich-text-editor > [data-testid="rich-text-editor"]');
```

That said, if you're testing rather than scraping, using "heavy" selectors and CSS often might be a code smell. Consider adding specific test ids to the top-level container `<div>` elements or using additional properties and structures that may be in your markup to keep your locators simple and avoid CSS selectors.

It may also be possible to [select based on layout](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#css-matching-elements-based-on-layout), depending on your use case (but this is not always reliable, so proceed with caution).

Comment: Note: Matching based on layout may produce unexpected results. For example, a different element could be matched when layout changes by one pixel.